# z-index for element however different positioning?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

Fast question; if you have 2 divs, one absolutley positioned and one relative, it isnt doing the z-index, i have attached a jsfiddle.

If i make them both relative they go with the flow of the DOM and one goes above the other on the y axis rather  than z, any ideas?

[Example JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wjw9j/2) (thanks Onheiron for fixing the render in jsfiddle)

Screenshot of whats happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmILA.png , the gray thing should be behind the image.

Thanks.

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't render.

Comment: Yeah I can see take a look at the screenshot in my OP

Comment: this fiddle renders : http://jsfiddle.net/Wjw9j/2/ there was a problem with double id css declaration, removed #midwrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a child appear behind it's parent! You can only do that with siblings.

See your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/Wjw9j/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my css looks like the attached; however still not rendering correctly in the browser. http://jsfiddle.net/Wjw9j/6/

Comment: @zomboble please describe "not correctly". Did you notice, that i modified the html to make it work? You can't achieve that with your original markup.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question, I need to explain stacking context.

When you add a z-index to an element, it creates a stacking context. All child elements are then compared to this parent stacking context.

Your element "slideImg" has a z-index of 1000. Any child elements are then compared within the stacking context of this parent element. So the z-index of "shadow", which is 0, is actually "1000 + 0", because it is within the stacking context of "slideImg".

To put "shadow" behind "slideImg" you can reverse their nesting:

```
    <div id="shadow">    
          <div id="slideImg"></div>    
    </div>
```

Or put them adjacent to each other, so they are each considered in the same stacking context.

```
    <div id="shadow"></div>
    <div id="slideImg"></div>
```

There is an [explanation of z-index and Stacking Context here](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201208/Blog/Z-Index-And-The-Stacking-Context/).